# Simple Proof of Universal Coefficient for the Field case

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Does there exist a simple proof of Universal Coefficient for the case of field coefficients?

For field $F$, we know that $$H^n(X;F)\cong Hom_F(H_n(X;F),F)$$

([Is homology with coefficients in a field isomorphic to cohomology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42581/is-homology-with-coefficients-in-a-field-isomorphic-to-cohomology))

Is there a simplified proof for this special case, that is simpler than the whole proof involving Ext?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through a standard proof, as in [Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html), you will find
a lot of shortcuts when doing things over a field. For instance
$$0\to Z_n\to C_n\to B_{n-1}\to0$$
will split, as every exact sequence splits over a field.
Dualising exact sequences gives exact sequences, so Hatcher's sequence
(vii) will be exact, and no Ext terms are needed.